# Is there a way to loop through a programmatically added array of SeekBars

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have created an array of SeekBars as following:

`private SeekBar sliders[] = new SeekBar[1020];`

I am interested in creating an `onSeekBarChangeListener` that will loop through the sliders array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may help you:

```
void registerSeekBarsListeners(sliders: Array<SeekBar>) {
  for (SeekBar slider: sliders) {
     slider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
        // PUT YOUR EVENT LISTENER CODE HERE
     }
  }
}
```

simply call `registerSeekBarsListeners` with your sliders array and you are ready to go (or at least debug)